# Issue with service List

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm trying to create some REST services. So I'm trying to change a few examples I have found online. I make the examples work adapting it to my Oracle database and my "where" clause of my choice with HQL.

So I runned my code and it seemed fine. The issue comes when I call the service instead of printing the diferent cases. It prints the exact number of cases in my databases. But all the cases printed are the same I have been looking around in other cases. But I couldn't find any case similar.

**Controller**

```
@GetMapping("/get/{IntParam}/{StringParam1}/{StringParam2}")
public ResponseEntity<List<DBO>> array(@PathVariable("IntParam") int IntParam, @PathVariable("StringParam1") String StringParam1, @PathVariable("StringParam2") String StringParam2) {List<DBO> dbo = DBOService.array(IntParam, StringParam1, StringParam2);
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(dbo);
```

}

**DaoImp**

```
@Override
public List<DBO> array(int IntParam, String StringParam1, String StringParam2) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    String hql = "FROM Database E WHERE E.StringParam1=:stringParam1 and E.StringParam2=:stringParam2 and E.IntParam = :intParam";
    Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
    query.setParameter("stringParam1", StringParam1);
    query.setParameter("stringParam2", StringParam2);
    query.setParameter("intParam", IntParam);
    List results = query.list();
    return results;
}
```

I expect the output to be different entries. As it is when I do the same Query directly to the database.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused because the model needed to be added "@Id" to the declaration. After that it was solved.